# Compare two CSV's and only run against the difference in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Sorry if I get a little long winded ahead of time but here goes!

**Back Story**

We are looking to automate the process for which we remediate Office 365 accounts that may potentially be compromised. This information is pulled via REST API from graph.microsoft.com and exported to a CSV containing the users UPN. Currently we go through and manually remediate each account using a separate script and that can perform this action in bulk against each user in the CSV. This can get get tedious having to check the report every so often so we are looking to automate this using one or more scripts.

**Problem**

Currently we have ~2000 MFA enabled users with roughly 10,000 to go and more being enabled every week. What we do not want to happen is users who end up on our risky users report/spreadsheet to be re-enabled which would force them to go through the process of re-configuring their MFA contact method/App.

**Desired Outcome**

Using any method, compare usernames from one CSV (Risky Users) to another CSV (MFA Enabled Users). Either output differences to another CSV so we can have our Remediation script run against that CSV or from within our remediation script only run against the users that do NOT appear on the MFA enabled Users CSV

**Currently In place**

Generate CSV from Risky Event via graph.microsoft.com
https://pastebin.com/MNChL3KY

Get Currently Enabled MFA Users and output to CSV
https://pastebin.com/kAHSpdW2

Remediate Accounts via CSV
https://pastebin.com/R818W9MM

Any type of tidbit, pointer to accomplish this would be immensely helpful I am definitively at little hangup.

Answer (score 3):

You may use a Powershell command to compare the two files as text using
[Compare-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-6):

```
powershell Compare-Object (gc FILE1) (gc FILE2)
```

The two files should be sorted first.

Comment: Let me give this a shot.  I was messing with this earlier but It wasnt giving me expected outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read all your code (visully impaired), but the basics of creating your desired CSV should be as simple as:

```
$Risky = Import-Csv -path '<path to Risky.csv>'
$MFAenabled = (Import-Csv -path '<path to MFAenabled.csv>').UserName

$Risky |
   Where-Object{$_.UserName -notin $MFAenabled} |
      Export-Csv -path '<path to new>'
```

Comment: Ill give that a shot and see what I come up with.